# Java program won't transfer files larger than 64KB

Tags: java, sockets, limit, file-transfer

I am making a program that sends a file from a server to the client. The program itself runs, and works for any file 64KB and under, but when I try to send a file larger than that it only transfers 64KB, for example, I tried sending a 232KB file test.txt, and the program only outputted a 64KB file receivedTest.txt.

Here is the server code

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class FileTransferServer {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ServerSocket servsock = new ServerSocket(1234);
    File myFile = new File("C:/Users/Owner/Downloads/test.txt");
    while (true) {
      Socket sock = servsock.accept();
      byte[] mybytearray = new byte[(int) myFile.length()];
      BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(myFile));
      bis.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
      OutputStream os = sock.getOutputStream();
      os.write(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
      os.flush();
      sock.close();
    }
}
}
```

And this is the client

```
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.Socket;

public class FileTransferClient {
public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
Socket sock = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 1234);
byte[] mybytearray = new byte[409600];
InputStream is = sock.getInputStream();

FileOutputStream fos=newFileOutputStream("C:/Users/Owner/Downloads/receivedTest.txt");
    BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
    int bytesRead = is.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
    bos.write(mybytearray, 0, bytesRead);
    bos.close();
    sock.close();
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, can't find out what's going on.

EDIT: Thanks everyone, it works now, I changed the client code to this:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class FileTransferClient {
  public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
    Socket sock = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 1234);
    byte[] mybytearray = new byte[1024];
    int count;
    InputStream is = sock.getInputStream();
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:/Users/Owner/Downloads/receivedTest.jpg");
    BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);

    while ((count = is.read(mybytearray)) > 0)
    {
        bos.write(mybytearray, 0, count);
    }
    bos.close();
    sock.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried writing/reading the file in chunks rather then as a whole?  Also, what happens when the file is over 400kb?

Comment: You know that `is.read` doesn't read the whole array, right? It reads "any number of bytes between 1 and mybytearray.length". Same for `bis.read` on the server. (`write` works like you'd expect, and writes the whole thing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usual issues.

1. You're assuming the file fits into memory.
2. You're assuming the file size fits into an int.
3. You're assuming that `read()` fills the buffer.

The canonical way to copy streams in java is as follows:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[8192]; // any size greater than 0 will work
int count;
while ((count = in,read(buffer)) > 0)
{
    out.write(buffer, 0, count);
}
```

I'm surprised you get as much as 64k from your code. Without a loop, you will only get one socket receive buffer-full, which can be as low as 8k on Windows.

Comment: Thanks, it worked, I changed the client code to this and it was able to transfer a 160KB file.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be writing the entire thing at once, especially not to a socket. You want to do something along the lines of

```
byte[] buf = new byte[4096];
int bytesRead = 0;
while((bytesRead = is.read(buf)) > 0){
    os.write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
}
```

This way you can read/write any size without running out of error and without worrying about things like running out of memory or getting an error for trying to send too large a request to the server.

Answer (score -1):

The way you're trying it will  gives you **OutOfMemoryError** because you are trying to read the entire file into memory until it is sent which completely unnecessary.

Best approach will be to read and write chunks, much as you are doing in the receiving code.

Comment: I'd love an explanation of these downvotes. Upvoting this one. There's no loop in his receiving code, but there's nothing wrong in saying the OP must read and write chunks. There is no other way.

Comment: It's a good recommendation, but obviously not the answer to the question. Whether it's a good idea to read entire files into memory or not depends entirely on the file size, and running out of memory on small file sizes is very unlikely.

Comment: @PeterWalser Reading and writing the file in chunks, *correctly,* ***is*** the answer to the question.